# jQuery SerialScroll: Add class to active item

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollto, serialscroll

I'm using Ariel Flesler's serialScroll script and would like to add a class to the active, or highlighted item so I can style it with CSS. Reading [the documentation](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) I discovered the notify trigger, but I'm not sure how / if it could be used to accomplish this.

This is my code:

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    $('#slideshow').serialScroll({
        items:'li',
        prev:'#screen2 a.prev',
        next:'#screen2 a.next',
        offset:-180,
        start: 0,
        duration:1200,
        force:true,
        stop:true,
        lock:false,
        cycle:false,
        jump: true
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="screen2">
    <div id="buttons">
        <a class="prev" href="#">Previous</a>
        <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/s/113497.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/s/100177.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/s/101916.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/animal-steps-in-snow-thumb12853223.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/animal-eggs-thumb15876342.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/animal-cat-thumb15385101.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/green-nature-thumb596309.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/office-in-nature-thumb3256171.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/nature-tree-thumb16030502.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/gift-of-the-nature-thumb15977958.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/nature-abstract-thumb3615419.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/nature-path-in-forest-with-sunshine-thumb8241130.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/nature-walk-thumb8436665.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.dreamstime.com/save-the-nature-thumb15696583.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I misunderstanding the function of the notify trigger? And if so, is there any alternate ways of accomplishing what I'm after?

Comment: I would have a look at the onBefore function - from the docs:
A function to be called before each scrolling. It receives the following arguments: event object, targeted element, element to be scrolled, collection of items and position of the targeted element in the collection.
The scope(this) will point to the element that got the event. If the function returns false, the event is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the plugin example page, here's how onBefore is being used:

```
onBefore:function( e, elem, $pane, $items, pos ){
    /**
    * 'this' is the triggered element 
    * e is the event object
    * elem is the element we'll be scrolling to
    * $pane is the element being scrolled
    * $items is the items collection at this moment
    * pos is the position of elem in the collection
    * if it returns false, the event will be ignored
    */
    //those arguments with a $ are jqueryfied, elem isn't.
}
```

in that function, you can add your active class, and use the onAfter function to remove the class from the previous element.